# Converting an n by 0 array to 0 by n array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode

Hi I'm trying to right an algorithm in obj-c. I have a NSMutableArray which is n by 0 but memory wise and iterating through it's a bit annoying. I wanted to change it to a single array.

```
a[0][0]  
a[1][0] 
a[2][0] 
a[3][0]  
a[4][0]
```

to

```
a[0]
a[1]
a[2]
a[3]
a[4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i;
NSMutableArray *newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for(i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {
    [newArray insertObject:array[i][0] atIndex:i];
}
NSLog(@"newArray %@],newArray);
```